# Get feePayer (Signer) from @project-serum/sol-wallet-adapter and use it in @solana/spl-token

Tags: solana-program, web3.js, solana-wallet-adapter, solana-cli, sdk

I used a package called @project-serum/sol-wallet-adapter and I want to use createMint() and mintTo() functions in @solana/spl-token. The problem is that I can't get the feePayer or the Signer in order to make createMint() work.

Code (what I need):

```
const mint = await Token.createMint(
        connection,
        wallet, // I need this signer which i cannot get from @project-serum/sol-wallet-adapter
        wallet.publicKey,
        wallet.publicKey,
        9,
        TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID
      );

// Everything else is good
```

If anybody can tell me a solution, that would be great!

Comment: No comments on this one ? If any of you have example how to createMint() on solana mainnet that would be great as well!

Answer (score 2):

When using a wallet, you have to use a different flow than the `Token` class, which is one of the reasons why it was removed.  Rather than passing in the `Keypair`, you'll need to create a transaction and have it signed by the wallet, ie:

```
const lamports = await getMinimumBalanceForRentExemptMint(connection);

const transaction = new Transaction().add(
    SystemProgram.createAccount({
        fromPubkey: payer.publicKey,
        newAccountPubkey: keypair.publicKey,
        space: MINT_SIZE,
        lamports,
        programId,
    }),
    createInitializeMint2Instruction(keypair.publicKey, decimals, mintAuthority, freezeAuthority, programId)
);
let { blockhash } = await connection.getRecentBlockhash();
transaction.recentBlockhash = blockhash;
transaction.feePayer = wallet.publicKey;
let signed = await wallet.signTransaction(transaction);
```

This was adapted from https://github.com/solana-labs/solana-program-library/blob/master/token/js/src/actions/createMint.ts